# Receiving error : the requested address '/' was not found on this server cakep php 2.7

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.7

Method not allowed exception received when trying to submit the action .
Under that error is : the requested address '/xyz/zyx/123' was not found on this server.

we dont have debug mode on for production server.
the external user is doing to action to submit the data.
This error occures sometimes not frequent to users.

code in controller :
$this->request->allowMethod('post');

code in ctp file :
echo $this->Form->postLink(
'Submit Documents for Pre-Qualification',
array(
'controller' => 'module_accreditations',
'action' => 'submit',
$moduleAccreditation['ModuleAccreditation']['id']
),
array(
'class' => 'small radius callout button module_submit_doc',
'confirm' => 'Upon submitting, you will be prevented from changing information included in these documents. Do you wish to continue?'
)
);

When user clicks on this submit and then confirm , the user receive the error as method not allowed with address not found

Workflow :
click on button ->
controller call to model ->
there are two method, one for save/ edit and another for update all on two different table->

and then email notification

Comment: If the method was allowed, you'd have a controller action for that specific verb and location. Do you have it?

Comment: yes, we have controller action if (!$this->request->is('post')) {
    throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
   }

Comment: You can increase the chances of getting an answer if you edit the question and include the relevant code there. In any case, knowing you reject non-POST request at an undisclosed location doesn't shed much light on the problem. We don't know what's being requested, or if you know for sure this is the offending line.

Comment: any connection with this error in nginx:  open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/dns-query" failed

Comment: Anyone have any idea about the error, we have recently implemented CSRF as well.